# SageMaker Batch Transform keeps failing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm able to train and deploy a model to a SageMaker Endpoint and able to get a response from the Endpoint successfully. But when I try to run a BatchTransform job, it keeps failing. Below is my project folder structure, train.py script, and my notebook. I used the AWS Console to launch batch transform job.

**Error**

```
JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 59, in default_input_fn    np_array = encoders.decode(input_data, content_type)  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_encoders.py", line 211, in decode    return decoder(obj)  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_encoders.py", line 97, in json_to_numpy    data = json.loads(string_like)  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads    return _default_decoder.decode(s)  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

**Project Folder structure:**

```
/
|
|__container
    |__code
        |__train.py
        |__requirements.txt
    |__Dockerfile
|__notebook.ipynb
|__build_and_push.sh
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG REGION=us-east-1

FROM 683313688378.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py3

ENV PATH="/opt/ml/code:${PATH}"

COPY /code /opt/ml/code

RUN pip install -r /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt

ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py
```

**train.py**

```
import os
import warnings
import sys
import json
import ast
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import logging
import pickle

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def eval_metrics(actual, pred):
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual, pred))
    mae = mean_absolute_error(actual, pred)
    r2 = r2_score(actual, pred)
    return rmse, mae, r2

if __name__ =='__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR'))
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'))
    parser.add_argument('--test', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_TEST'))
    parser.add_argument('--train-file', type=str, default='kc_house_data_train.csv')
    parser.add_argument('--test-file', type=str, default='kc_house_data_test.csv')
    parser.add_argument('--features', type=str)  
    parser.add_argument('--target', type=str) 

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    np.random.seed(40)

    # Reading training and testing datasets
    logging.info('reading training and testing datasets')
    train_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.train, args.train_file))
    test_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.test, args.test_file))
    train_x = np.array(train_df[args.features.split(',')]).reshape(-1,1)
    test_x = np.array(test_df[args.features.split(',')]).reshape(-1,1)
    train_y = np.array(train_df[args.target]).reshape(-1,1)
    test_y = np.array(test_df[args.target]).reshape(-1,1)
     
     reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
     reg.fit(train_x, train_y)

     predicted = reg.predict(test_x)

     (rmse, mae, r2) = eval_metrics(test_y, predicted)
        
      logging.info(f"        Linear model: (features={args.features}, target={args.target})")
      logging.info(f"            RMSE: {rmse}")
      logging.info(f"            MAE: {mae}")
      logging.info(f"            R2: {r2}")
      logging.info(f"    Tags: {args.tags}") 

      # Save model
      model_path = os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.pkl")
      logging.info(f"saving to {model_path}")
      with open(model_path, 'wb') as path:
          pickle.dump(reg, path)

def model_fn(model_dir):
    with open(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.pkl"), "rb") as input_model:
        model = pickle.load(input_model)
    return model
    
def predict_fn(data, model):
    return model.predict(data)
```

**notebook**

```
import sagemaker as sm
from sagemaker.predictor import  json_serializer, json_deserializer


sm_role = sm.get_execution_role()
___
image_uri = '8345678891234.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-test:latest'
___

hyperparameters = {
    'features': 'sqft_living',
    'target': 'price'
    }
local_mode = False
___

Estimator = sm.estimator.Estimator

estimator = Estimator(
    role = sm_role,
    train_instance_count = 1,
    train_instance_type = 'local' if local_mode else 'ml.m5.large',
    image_name = image_uri,
    base_job_name = 'housing-price-prediction',
    hyperparameters = hyperparameters,
    subnets=['subnet-b88aa077', 
             'subnet-u45673d1'],
    security_group_ids=['sg-c08b6532']
    
)   
___

estimator.fit(
    {'train':'s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-1234567/housing-price-prediction/curated/train', 
     'test':'s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-1234567/housing-price-prediction/curated/test'},
     wait=False,
     logs=True)

___
predictor = estimator.deploy(instance_type='ml.t2.medium',
                 initial_instance_count=1)   
predictor.accept = 'application/json'
predictor.content_type = 'application/json'
predictor.serializer = json_serializer
predictor.deserializer = json_deserializer
___
predict_data = pd.read_csv("s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-1234567/housing-price-prediction/curated/predict/kc_house_data_predict.csv")
get_prediction=np.array(predict_data['sqft_living']).reshape(-1,1)
predictor.predict(data=get_prediction) #Prediction from real-time endpoint was successful
```

**SageMaker Batch Transform Job setup using console**

> Job name:  Model name:

> Instance type: ml.m5.large  Instance count: 1 S3 Data type: S3 Prefix

> Content type: 'application/x-npy' S3 location:

> 's3://<bucket_name>/predict/input/' S3 output path:

> 's3://<bucket_name>/predict/output/'
>
> Rest all I left it as default and hit `create job`